# MYSQL UNION ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    images
WHERE   images.id IN (SELECT image_id FROM image_likes WHERE user_id = '1')
    UNION
SELECT * 
FROM images
WHERE images.user_id = '1' AND upload_type in (4,3) ORDER BY id DESC
```

And this works great, but now i want it to display the most recent results thats have happend.
For example, User A uploaded a image-> information goes into `images` with a timestamp. User A then likes someone else's image -> Information goes into `image_likes` with a timestamp. Now how would i make the two timestamp column's merge together so i can sort them by DESC.

Breif run over of what the query does.
Selects the image information from `images` where the user has liked a image in `image_likes` and then it grabs all of the uploads the user has uploaded from `images` and merges them into a query. What i need is to be able to sort them using the `timestamp` from both tables.

Comment: What timestamp? you've not shown us the structure of the tables - and 'select *' is just messy programming

Comment: I need all of the information from the results. And there are timestamps in both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about doing this??

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    images
    WHERE   images.id IN (SELECT image_id FROM image_likes WHERE user_id = '1')
        UNION
    SELECT * 
    FROM images
    WHERE images.user_id = '1' AND upload_type in (4,3) ORDER BY id DESC
) AS a ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC;
```

OR even better

```
 (SELECT  *
    FROM images
    WHERE images.id IN (SELECT image_id FROM image_likes WHERE user_id = '1'))
        UNION
 (SELECT * 
    FROM images
    WHERE images.user_id = '1' AND upload_type in (4,3) ORDER BY id DESC)
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

chk this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

**UPDATE**

TRY THIS

```
 (SELECT images.id, images_likes.timestamp as timestamp FROM images JOIN images_likes 
    ON images.id=image_likes.image_id WHERE user_id = '1')
        UNION
 (SELECT images.id, images.timestamp as timestamp
    FROM images
    WHERE images.user_id = '1' AND upload_type in (4,3) ORDER BY id DESC)
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

**UPDATE**

Final query as per your requirement

```
 (SELECT images.id, images.user_id, images.ext, images.upload_type, images_likes.timestamp as timestamp FROM images JOIN images_likes 
    ON images.id=image_likes.image_id WHERE images_likes.user_id = '1')
        UNION
 (SELECT images.id, images.user_id, images.ext, images.upload_type, images.timestamp as timestamp
    FROM images
    WHERE images.user_id = '1' AND upload_type in (4,3) ORDER BY id DESC)
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: I am afraid it doesnt merge the two timestamp fields from images.timestamp and image_likes.timestamp and then sorts them :/

Comment: Ok so you want the first part of the union also ordered by the timestamp of images_like ???

Comment: What the query is made to do is basically. Look to see if the user has liked any images, if they have grab the images information from `images` and then also grab the information of the images the user has uploaded. Their is a timestamp in both tables so i need them merged so i can for example show a image that has been liked 1 minute ago before a image they uploaded 2 minutes ago :)

Comment: it has came back saying Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: replace WHERE user_id with WHERE image_likes.user_id

Comment: Now it has only returned two columns "id" and "timestamp" rather than all of the images information

Comment: ye ofcourse....cos the query asks it to do so....if u can then give me the attributes that both the tables have and what all do you finally require...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9963/discussion-between-sandeep-rajoria-and-trendee)

Answer (score 1):

I would approach with the following...  The "PreQuery" below starts with all images the user likes first, with the max timestamp as a new column "MostRecent".  THEN, do a UNION ALL for the next set.  The next set is directly from the images table for the user, but LEFT JOINED to the "Liked" images.  Then the WHERE clause explicitly excludes those that would have been returned in the first set by using the "iml2.image_id IS NULL".  I did this as I wasn't positive on how the union would handle the group by in the first set, but no group by in the second.  Ex: If the image was created with date/timestamp of say Mar 3, but also found as a "Like" of Mar 5, I didn't want one instance listed as each distinct date (as union already qualifies distinct implied).

That said, I will have a single prequery result of any image the person liked with its most recent date/time stamp, AND all their own personal images with their respective date/time stamp.  Now, its a simple join back to the images table to grab the details (via alias "i2") and we can sort by the PreQuery.MostRecent column, then by the image ID value descending.

```
SELECT
      i2.*
   from
      ( select iml.image_id as id,
               max( iml.YourTimeStamp ) as MostRecent
           from image_likes iml
           where iml.user_id = '1'
           group by iml.image_id

        UNION ALL

        select i.id,
               i.ImageTimeStamp as MostRecent
           from images i
              left join image_likes iml2
                 on i.id = iml2.image_id
                 and iml2.user_id = '1'
           where i.user_id = '1'
             and i.upload_type in ( 4, 3 )
             and iml2.image_id is null 
      ) PreQuery
         JOIN Images i2
            on PreQuery.id = i2.id
   order by
      PreQuery.MostRecent,
      PreQuery.ID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a 'OR'?

that way :

```
  SELECT  *
  FROM    images
  WHERE   images.id IN (SELECT image_id FROM image_likes WHERE user_id = '1')
      OR  (images.user_id = '1' AND upload_type in (4,3))
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  ( SELECT  im.*
          , li.timestamp AS ts
    FROM    images AS im 
      JOIN  image_likes AS li
        ON  li.image_id = im.image_id
    WHERE   li.user_id = 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT *
         , timestamp AS ts
    FROM images 
    WHERE user_id = 1 
      AND upload_type in (4,3) 
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY ts DESC
```