# Sort two table's by date and show output in html <table>

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, date

I have a PHP code ready which will fetch data from a mysql database,The PHP code will also display the data in tabular form.

**What I want to Achieve:**

I have a dummy database named "stackoverflow" with two tables "customer" & "receipt"
both of these tables have a field called "date" with datatype as date as well.
[full schema here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpnHH.png)

I want some selected entries from these tables to appear in an html table.
the entries should be sorted by date in increasing order.

**What I have tried and accomplished:**

The data is fetched and shown in tabular form successfully, but date wise sorting is partially complete.

[output of my result (without php code since jsfiddle doesn't support php)](http://jsfiddle.net/UPktn/2/)

I have used PHP to compare dates between dates of each table and then show the respective data

```
<?php
        while( $kb = mysql_fetch_assoc($customer) ){
            customer_data($kb); //function which echos <tr>'s of customer table
                while($cd = mysql_fetch_assoc($reciept)){ //function which echos <tr>'s of reciept table
                    if($cd['date'] <= $kb['date']){
                    reciept_data($cd);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

**Problems I am facing:**

The sorting is not exactly like what I wanted. (only some of them are as per increasing date order).

link to my whole project file with database schema and sample data (just import into phpmyadmin) for reference: http://www.mediafire.com/?bcbvkn8uq89ya6n

If you are still confused about what kind of output I am trying to get.I made a table in excel here's the Image: [image]

I am struggling with this problem since a couple of days. I think this is due to my lack of sql skills?. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

This is how I pickup data from the tables using php:

```
$customer = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_name = '$name' ORDER BY date ASC ");

$reciept = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reciept WHERE name = '$name' ORDER BY date ASC");
```

After some research, I came across the UNION operator which joins two select statements, and I developed this query:

```
SELECT DATE, customer_name, grand_total
FROM customer
WHERE customer_name =  'JHON'
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATE, name, recd_amount
FROM reciept
WHERE name =  'JHON'
```

but I could only select equal no. of columns in both select statements, and how do I order by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use '==' for equality comparison in if statement. '=' will assign a value to the variable

```
   if($cd['date'] = $kb['date']){
```

to

```
   if($cd['date'] == $kb['date']){
```

Order by in union

```
 $query = " (SELECT DATE, customer_name, grand_total
FROM customer
WHERE customer_name =  'JHON')
UNION ALL 
    (SELECT DATE, name, recd_amount
     FROM reciept
     WHERE name =  'JHON')
    order by  customer.Date desc"
```

a helping link 
 [MYSQL UNION ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106109/mysql-union-order-by)

Comment: thanks for that! but that changes my output totally, "<=" operator is the one I am using now.but the problem still persists.

Comment: I thought you are doing equality comparison. let  us try

Comment: the equality operator excludes results from "reciept" table. so I am using the "<=" operator which gives me the same result which I am getting in the jsfiddle link.

Comment: please put you dates in inside strtotime function then see if it works. if(strtotime($cd['date']) <= strtotime($kb['date']))

Comment: yes! its works. but the output is the same. I think you are missing out that my problem is that the first two entries in yellow (in the image) appear later in the table and not as per date..... maybe because they are from "reciept" table and the outer while loop starts with "customer" table....I hope I am clear explaining you this. sorry!

Comment: ok. do you have relation in both tables. are you using join to pick data from database?

Comment: no. I dont have any joints!. I just use simple select statements for obtaining data. and store them in different variables. I am weak in SQL.check my update in OP.

Comment: if you can give it a try and (if customer can have many receipts) then add customer table pk as foreign key in receipt table and the doing a join can help in your query

Comment: customer table stores the bill of a ledger(a person) and reciept table stores the payment info of that bill against that ledger.will the table relationship still work? any way to do without relationships?..can you start a chat. I have less repo to do that.

Comment: chat can not be started as it has given an error that you have only 3 reputation, not enough to chat

Comment: if your ledger  / bill table has more then one payment info then it can have foreign key. if one bill has only one payment then it is a diff case you can still add bill table key to payment info table and do a join

Comment: yes one bill has only one payment!..how about UNION ALL operation. can it sort by dates? did you had a look at my project file.

Comment: i have edited answer. for ordering in union all please try. I just added for reference you can do editing as your own requirement

Comment: Thanks again!...but I get this error: ....Table 'customer' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Comment: ok remove customer from order by clause  from customer.Date. do only  order by Date desc. please try.

Comment: FInally!! Thanks so much dude..I will try to implement this.lets see If this works, I will revert back with my output.